# Changing time interval in weekly calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Right now my `Weekly Calendar` shows up with one hour of interval. I'd like to know if it's possible to change this interval as I like (e.g 1hour30min interval).

My code to build the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: false,  
    height: 800,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

    views: {
        week: {
            columnFormat: 'dddd'
        }
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    weekends: false,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  header: false,
  height: 800,
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

  views: {
    week: {
      columnFormat: 'dddd'
    }
  },
  firstDay: 1,
  weekends: false,
  allDaySlot: false,
  slotDuration: "01:30:00"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ax71o58/

Answer (score 1):

You can set [slotLabelInterval](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotLabelInterval/):

```
slotLabelInterval: "01:30:00"
```